# sympy nontrivial substitutions

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to make some substitutions in sympy, but they are not generally of the form `x=1` etc.  More like `(a+b)/(c+d)=1`.  I could pick an arbitrary variable to solve for, but there exist circumstances in which that might produce infinite solutions, possibly creating infinite possible substitutions, and whatever other unknown unknown caveats, when a direct replacement would not.

To illustrate what I am trying to do, consider:

[image: sympy]

This is clearly just `1`.  How do I get sympy to output `1` for this?

**UPDATE**

This also doesn't work:

```
sp.solvers.solve([(a+b)/(c+d)-x,(c+d)/(a+b)-1],x)
```

Comment: What you're looking for isn't really a substitution.

Comment: so I should use a different method?  do you have a reference?

Comment: this: `expr = sp.sin(2*x) + sp.cos(2*x);
expr.subs(sp.sin(2*x), 2*sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(x))` DOES work, and it seems to be a similar circumstance, but not quite.

Comment: The octave "symbolic" package function `subs` does the exact same thing.... otoh, it looks like octave "symbolic" and sympy may be related somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the system you set up for two variables, rather than just one. This will force SymPy to actually use both equations.

```
sp.solve([(a+b)/(c+d) - x, (c+d)/(a+b) - 1], [x, a])
```

outputs `{a: -b + c + d, x: 1}`

Or more specifically,

```
sp.solvers.solve([(a+b)/(c+d) - x, (c+d)/(a+b) - 1], [x, a])[x]
```

outputs 1.

Generally, the process described above is "eliminating a", but in the specific example it simultaneously eliminates b, c, d.

---

> direct replacement would not

Direct replacement means replacing a part of expression tree. The expression (a+b)/(c+d) does **not** contain (c+d)/(a+b) anywhere in its tree, so there is nothing that a direct replacement could do.